# Rmarkdown says a unicode character not set up for LaTeX but I can't find that character

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to use Rmarkdown within RStudio to render a pdf file, but I'm getting the error
`! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Î¦ (U+3A6)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.`

I must have inadvertently copied and pasted a Phi symbol somewhere, but I have no idea *where* in my 2000+ line .Rmd file that symbol is. How can I find the offending character so I can deal with it? I've tried searching my script for a capital Phi with RStudio, opening my file in Notepad++ to search there, etc. and I can't find it.

Comment: Did you also search for Î ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It can't find it.

Comment: Is it possible to upload your code? We can have a look ...

Comment: Yes, here's a link: https://github.com/shirewoman2/Public/blob/master/GDM%20summary%20graphs%20and%20analyses.Rmd

Comment: The problem, though, is that I've had similar problems before, and I'd like to know in general how to find where a special character is that's mucking up knitting. Even if I find it this time, I know this will happen again. Thank you!